# Excel 2010 : How to compute the number of non blank cells in a column among the entire workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

Let's say I want to compute the number of non blank cells in some column (A for exemple) among the entire workbook, for a fixed range of cells. How can I do this ? knowing that for just one worksheet, `COUNTA(rangeOfCells)` can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter a 3-dimensional formula. This will evaluate every worksheet between (and including) the start `(Sheet1)` and end `(Sheet3)` worksheets you're interested in.

```
=COUNTA(Sheet1:Sheet3!A1:A99)
```

Comment: you saved me a lot of time !! it's a pity I can't upvote you ! thanks man !

Comment: you can now if you want ;)

Comment: it's me who upvoted you..

Comment: Was only kidding but very kind of you!